# How to install latest is-callable version 1.1.5?

Tags: angular, npm

I run `npm install` and I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
>   npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for is-callable@^1.1.5.
>   npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
>   npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/MyUserName/.npm/_logs/2020-02-04T09_15_04_696Z-debug.log

I have been trying following commands:

```
npm rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

But it didn't help.

Even when trying to remove **`node_modules`**, I got the same error.

When I try to install the latest version of `is-callable` which should be: [`1.1.5`](https://github.com/inspect-js/is-callable), I just get the version: `1.1.4`

npm version: `6.12.0`

angular version: `8.x`

Typescript version: `3.4.5`

Any idea or hint to come around this issue? Should I go for npm version: `6.13.1` which ist the latest one?

Comment: could you try with `npm install --force

Comment: `npm install --force` didn't help

Comment: could you try with `yarn`

Comment: Yes, I could, but I don't want. I tried it once and it did cause me couple of other issues. Therefore I keep using npm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `package.json` resolution to force selected version if you'd like.

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "resolutions": {
    "is-callable": "1.1.5"
  }
}
```

```
rm -r node_modules
npx npm-force-resolutions
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a solution:

```
   npm uninstall is-callable
   npm cache verify
   npm install
   npm install --save is-callable@latest
```